# SelectedIndex DataTrigger not working in Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datatrigger

What I want to do is if a combobox has only **1 item** then it gets **preselected**. I tried usind DataTriggers but its not working for '**SelectedIndex**' property.But when I set '**IsEnabled**' property to **false** its working and disable the combobox.

Below is my code:

```
<ComboBox  Name="WarehouseCombo" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WarehouseList}"
      SelectedValue="{Binding Warehouse,Mode=TwoWay}"
      Text="{Binding Path=TxtWarehouse,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBox.Style>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                         <DataTrigger
                              Binding="{Binding Path=Items.Count, ElementName=WarehouseCombo}" Value="1">
                                  <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
                          </DataTrigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
         </ComboBox.Style>
 </ComboBox>
```

Please help me as why is this happening in 'SelectedIndex' case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `SelectedIndex` property. Instead, use the `SelectedItem` property. One way to fulfil your requirements is to declare a base class for your data collection. Try something like this:

```
public WarehouseList : ObservableCollection<WarehouseItems>
{
    private T currentItem;

    public WarehouseList() { }

    public T CurrentItem { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged here

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
        if (Count == 1) CurrentItem = item;
    }
}
```

Now if you use this class instead of a standard collection, it will automatically set the first item as selected. To make this work in the UI, you simply need to data bind this property to the `SelectedItem` property like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding WarehouseList}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding WarehouseList.CurrentItem}" />
```